# What were Node.js isolates? And why are they now dead?

Tags: node.js

In 0.7.0, ["Experimenetal isolates support"](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/01/16/node-v0-7-0-unstable/) [sic] was introduced. I never understood this besides some vague idea that they gave threading-like capabilities but without the problems of threads. And maybe were good for solving Node's debugging/error handling story.

But, nobody ever explained what they were, either in that blog, or in the first few Google results. What are isolates? Why were they introduced to Node?

---

This morning, a bunch of GitHub issues ([2662](https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/2662#issuecomment-3798941), [2663](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2663#issuecomment-3798952), [2665](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2665#issuecomment-3798972), and probably more) were closed with the comment "isolates is dead". What happened? Why did this supposedly good idea, which from what I could tell was the headline feature for 0.7, die?

Comment: As far as I know _isolates_ were separate node v8 instances which ran as threads in a single process. (note that the usage of the term has nothing to do with dart's usage of the same term.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Explained here: http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/msg/6b8b8a487d2ab817

Ben just scooped me before I could get the message sent :)

Comment: you mentioned 'instead focus on Domains and other things that 
promise to increase stability and make debugging easier'. Now what is domains? is there any additional information out there for domains? I think i heard ryan explaining domains somewhere to isolate actions. But curious to find additional information.

Comment: @mamu More info is coming soon.  The premise of domains is to group different IO actions together, so that errors can be handled in a single place per-request, instead of per-process.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case the [link](http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/msg/6b8b8a487d2ab817) @isaacs postet ever breaks, here the contents:

> The Isolates feature was intended to make it possible to run
>   child_process.fork() in a thread, rather than a full process.  The
>   justification was to make it cheaper to spin up new child node
>   instances, as well as allowing for fast message-passing using shared
>   memory in binary addons, while retaining the semantics of node's
>   child_process implementation by keeping them in completely isolated v8
>   instances.
>
> It was a very informative experiment, but has ultimately turned out to
>   cause too much instability in node's internal functionality to justify
>   continuing with it at this time.  It requires a lot of complexity to
>   be added to libuv and node, and isn't likely to yield enough gains to
>   be worth the investment.
>
> We're going to roll back the changes in master that were added to
>   support Isolates, and instead focus on Domains and other things that
>   promise to increase stability and make debugging easier.  This change
>   will land in 0.7.3.  It's entirely possible that we may decide to use
>   v8 isolates in some future version of node, but they will not be in
>   0.8.
>
> If you were eagerly looking forward to using this feature, and find
>   yourself shocked or frustrated by this decision, please contact me
>   directly.  It's not our intention to leave anyone stuck, and I do
>   understand that this feature was promised for some time.  If this
>   causes hardship for you, let's figure out another way to get your use
>   cases handled.
>
> It's never easy to back-pedal, but doing experimental things means
>   sometimes finding out that you were headed in the wrong direction. The
>   sooner we make this change, the easier it will be.
>
> Thanks.

Comment: Too bad this was phased-out. Cloudflare just released Workers using V8 isolates directly, and I wish I could have this on Node. https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cloudflare-workers/

Answer (score 1):

You can think of Isolate as an independent instance of V8 runtime. It has own memory management (GC). The name comes from Chrome execution engine where you have multiple tabs and each tab has own JavaScript environment engine. Each tab (and JS environment) has to be 'isolated' from each other, so none of the page can access another page environment (window.local or window.document). That is the reason why V8 has Isolate object, which allows it to run in parallel multiple environments (pages/tabs) independent (isolated) from each other.