# node.js lacking use of `V8: Isolates`

Tags: node.js, v8, embedded-v8

node.js is built using V8 engine.

Yet doesn't explicitly use `V8: Isolates` or expose its process granular level isolation capabilities out-of-the-box.

Why?

I am wondering - shouldn't it be easier to expose Isolates, given V8 is used under the hood?
I haven't used node.js extensively yet to have *internals level* insight, so excuse me if this question is way too obvious.

I looked at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131902) question. It's related, though I've been interested in understanding reason for node.js not exposing `V8: Isolates` as-is; 
As against attempting to wrap it within it's own child_process implement.
Trust this nuances the diff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What were Node.js isolates? And why are they now dead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131902/what-were-node-js-isolates-and-why-are-they-now-dead)

Comment: [What were Node.js isolates and why are they now dead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131902/what-were-node-js-isolates-and-why-are-they-now-dead)

Answer (score 0):

Node actually did just start exposing this: https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html

Each worker is a separate isolate, but that is an implementation detail. Think of these like node-style web workers.